AVD in Android Emulator keeps rotating when running GPX record playback
I am using Android Studio to develop an App in Java.
My Android Studio version is Iguana 2023.2.1
My Android Emulator version is 34.1.20
I run AVD with Android Emulator to check the App functionality.
My issue is when ever I try to use Location in Extended Control tab of the AVD to load my GPX file and run Data playback (speed x1), the AVD starts rotating until it completes following the path.
This weird behavior of the AVD is very annoying if my team want to do any demo to customers.
Is there any permanent solution for this?
